# Android- How to call a IntentService just when the user is not using the app

Tags: android, polling, intentservice

I have a IntentService that will periodicaly ( once a day) erase the actual database and repopulate it with recent feeds and after that will send a notification to the user.
The problem that I have is when the user is using the app at the same time that IntentService poll the server. 
He is looking at a old feed that is not anymore in the database and if he clicks at any item the app crash. 
I want to know if there is a way to connect the server only when the app is not being used at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways.  Do you want to skip the day if it runs at the wrong time, or put it off?

If you want to skip it (the easiest)-  have a static variable in your Service class that's set to true when the Activity's onCreate is called, and false in onDestroy.  Have the Service check the value of that variable before touching the DB.

If you want to put it off, the same idea works but use a semaphore.

This works to stop the service if the activity is already running.  The opposite order would still crash.  To fix that, you'd need to have your activity check in the same manner as the service, but set a UI that says "synching try again later" or something similar if the service is already running.